# Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 To Ubuntu 12.10 Secure-Remix

Tags: uefi

Is it possible to upgrade an existing Ubuntu 12.04 install to Ubuntu 12.10 Secure-Remix? If so, could that HD be swapped into a new UEFI PC (as the only HD) and would it boot?

Comment: Update to 12.10 and install the software described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2073446)...done. Also bear in mind using that spin-off that you'll be using a non official Ubuntu derivative, making any questions you ask here about it **off-topic**. And just as an extra "Functionalities: same functionalities as the normal Ubuntu CD".

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to upgrade an existing Ubuntu 12.04 install to Ubuntu
>   12.10 Secure-Remix?

Yes, you can upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 Secure Remix, by:

- either using a 12.10SecureRemix this way:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation
- or upgrading
  from 12.04 to standard 12.10, then install Boot-Repair and
  OS-Uninstaller. (in your situation, Clean-Ubiquity is useless).

> If so, could that HD be swapped into a new UEFI PC (as the only HD)
>   and would it boot?

No, you can't upgrade and change your HD's partitioning type (MsDos <-> GPT/UEFI) at the same time.

Comment: This comment worries me: "No, you can't upgrade and change your HD's partitioning type (MsDos <-> GPT/UEFI) at the same time." 
The preceding discussion led me to believe that upgrading to 12.10 would enable me to boot from the drive on a UEFI PC - now 
you seem to be saying no. OK, can you tell me what it is I can do to enable Ubuntu on the new PC? As mentioned, I don't want 
to dual-boot or even use the HD that will ship with the PC. I would love to use my existing install by simply swapping in the
drive it's on, but if I can't do that how to I install Ubuntu on the new PC on a clean HD?

Comment: Please don't mistake: the partitioning type (either MsDos or GPT) is not related to the firmware type (BIOS or UEFI). Please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI for better understanding. If you want to install on a new HD, then install a new Ubuntu, and import your settings (hidden files inside your old /home folder).